# Receiver app: HLS media fails to load with InvalidStateError

Tags: http-live-streaming, google-cast, chromecast

Using the unmodified [cast-custom-receiver](https://github.com/googlecast/cast-custom-receiver) example, I keep getting an uncaught InvalidStateError exception in the media_player.js library when attempting to load a HLS media stream.  My HLS stream has three variants.

I don't believe this is a CORS issue as both my receiver app and video source are currently hosted together on S3 for testing purposes.

For the record, I'm using a simple Chrome sender (a modified version of [CastHelloVideo-chrome](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-chrome)) and have posted both [sender](http://stvdemo.s3.amazonaws.com/chromecast/sender.html) and [receiver](http://stvdemo.s3.amazonaws.com/chromecast/receiver.html) source publicly to Amazon S3 as well as the [HLS](http://stvdemo.s3.amazonaws.com/chromecast/video/tv.main.hls-0.m3u8) stream I'm using for testing.

Here is the receiver console output I see when the sender triggers the load media event:

```
 [  0.919s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Opening message bus websocket
 [  0.931s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc
 [  0.970s] [goog.net.WebSocket] WebSocket opened on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc
 [  0.980s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel opened
 [  0.989s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system, SystemSender]: {"type":"opened"}
 [  0.996s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] CastReceiverManager message received: [object Object]
 [  1.000s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Underlying message bus is open
 [  1.003s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender","data":"{\"type\":\"ready\",\"statusText\":\"Ready to play\",\"activeNamespaces\":[\"urn:x-cast:com.google.devrel.custom\",\"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media\"],\"version\":\"2.0.0\",\"messagesVersion\":\"1.0\"}"}
 [  1.015s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender","data":"{\"type\":\"startheartbeat\",\"maxInactivity\":6000}"}
 [  1.025s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"applicationId\":\"CE156522\",\"applicationName\":\"Simple.TV Test\",\"launchingSenderId\":\"4:client-68913\",\"messagesVersion\":\"1.0\",\"sessionId\":\"A2A4AA7B-5CE5-9CA0-38CA-EEC77B84F4C6\",\"type\":\"ready\",\"version\":\"1.0\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
 [  1.028s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system, SystemSender]: {"applicationId":"CE156522","applicationName":"Simple.TV Test","launchingSenderId":"4:client-68913","messagesVersion":"1.0","sessionId":"A2A4AA7B-5CE5-9CA0-38CA-EEC77B84F4C6","type":"ready","version":"1.0"}
 [  1.030s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] CastReceiverManager message received: [object Object]
 [  1.032s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching CastReceiverManager system ready event [[object Object]]
### Cast Receiver Manager is READY: {"type":"ready","B":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"Qa":true,"data":{"id":"CE156522","name":"Simple.TV Test","sessionId":"A2A4AA7B-5CE5-9CA0-38CA-EEC77B84F4C6","namespaces":["urn:x-cast:com.google.devrel.custom","urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media"],"launchingSenderId":"4:client-68913"}} 
 [  1.087s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"senderId\":\"4:client-68913\",\"type\":\"senderconnected\",\"userAgent\":\"\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
 [  1.089s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system, SystemSender]: {"senderId":"4:client-68913","type":"senderconnected","userAgent":""}
 [  1.092s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] CastReceiverManager message received: [object Object]
 [  1.094s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching CastReceiverManager sender connected event [4:client-68913]
 [  1.096s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.devrel.custom, 4:client-68913]
 [  1.098s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media, 4:client-68913]
### Cast Receiver Manager - Sender Connected : {"type":"senderconnected","B":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"Qa":true,"data":"4:client-68913"} 
 [ 21.168s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"type\":\"LOAD\",\"requestId\":90616069,\"sessionId\":\"A2A4AA7B-5CE5-9CA0-38CA-EEC77B84F4C6\",\"media\":{\"contentId\":\"http://stvdemo.s3.amazonaws.com/chromecast/video/tv.main.hls-0.m3u8\",\"streamType\":\"buffered\",\"contentType\":\"application/x-mpegURL\",\"metadata\":null,\"duration\":1800,\"customData\":null},\"autoplay\":false,\"currentTime\":0,\"customData\":null}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"4:client-68913"}
 [ 21.174s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media, 4:client-68913]: {"type":"LOAD","requestId":90616069,"sessionId":"A2A4AA7B-5CE5-9CA0-38CA-EEC77B84F4C6","media":{"contentId":"http://stvdemo.s3.amazonaws.com/chromecast/video/tv.main.hls-0.m3u8","streamType":"buffered","contentType":"application/x-mpegURL","metadata":null,"duration":1800,"customData":null},"autoplay":false,"currentTime":0,"customData":null}
 [ 21.183s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] MediaManager message received [4:client-68913] {"type":"LOAD","requestId":90616069,"sessionId":"A2A4AA7B-5CE5-9CA0-38CA-EEC77B84F4C6","media":{"contentId":"http://stvdemo.s3.amazonaws.com/chromecast/video/tv.main.hls-0.m3u8","streamType":"buffered","contentType":"application/x-mpegURL","metadata":null,"duration":1800,"customData":null},"autoplay":false,"currentTime":0,"customData":null}
 [ 21.187s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Dispatching MediaManager load event
### Media Manager - LOAD: {"type":"load","B":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"Qa":true,"data":{"requestId":90616069,"sessionId":"A2A4AA7B-5CE5-9CA0-38CA-EEC77B84F4C6","media":{"contentId":"http://stvdemo.s3.amazonaws.com/chromecast/video/tv.main.hls-0.m3u8","streamType":"buffered","contentType":"application/x-mpegURL","metadata":null,"duration":1800,"customData":null},"autoplay":false,"currentTime":0,"customData":null},"senderId":"4:client-68913"}
### Media Protocol Identified as m3u8
######### MEDIA ELEMENT LOAD START
Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable. media_player.js:101
######### MEDIA ELEMENT ERROR [object Event]
 [ 22.299s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error
### Media Manager - LOAD METADATA ERROR: {"senderId":"4:client-68913","message":{"requestId":90616069,"sessionId":"A2A4AA7B-5CE5-9CA0-38CA-EEC77B84F4C6","media":{"contentId":"http://stvdemo.s3.amazonaws.com/chromecast/video/tv.main.hls-0.m3u8","streamType":"buffered","contentType":"application/x-mpegURL","metadata":null,"duration":1800,"customData":null},"autoplay":false,"currentTime":0,"customData":null}} 
 [ 22.310s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Resetting media element
 [ 22.319s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending error message to 4:client-68913
 [ 22.324s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"4:client-68913","data":"{\"requestId\":90616069,\"type\":\"LOAD_FAILED\"}"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the report; I have opened an internal issue to get this to one of our engineers to take a look at.

Comment: Your stream is not conforming to the specs; from HLS specification:

"4.  Media segments
Each media segment MUST be formatted as an MPEG-2 Transport Stream or an MPEG-2 audio elementary stream [ISO_13818].
Transport Stream segments MUST contain a single MPEG-2 Program."

Your stream violates that and that is why it is not supported on Chromecast.